# AngularJS: How to preselect first option in filtered select

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

There are many questions and answers on SO for preselecting the first element in a select in angularjs, but I cannot find any help when the ng-options on the select are *filtering* the options, i.e. when you don't know what the first option will be. Consider the following scenario:

```
<select id="color" ng-model="vm.color" ng-options="color.name for color in vm.colors | filter: {hide: false} | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
```

Most answers to the many similar questions I have read suggest simply adding:`ng-init="vm.color=vm.colors[0]"` or doing the same thing in the controller. In my case, however, that won't work, because `vm.colors[0]` might not be the first element in the select due to the fact that the select is ordering the options alphabetically by name, and furthermore, it might not appear in the list *at all*, depending on the state of the "hide" flag.

I could definitely do some sort of function in the controller to getFirstVisibleColor() or something that would return the first one sorted alphabetically that isn't set to be hidden, but that'd be duplicating the logic in the select. I feel like there should be an option here to simply select the first one. I think I understand *why* angular defaults to creating an empty option, that is, so as not to let the rendering of the view make unintended changes to the controller (viewmodel), but in this case, that's exactly what I want!

Comment: It would only duplicate the logic if you keep the logic in the view. If you **move** it to the controller, and thus expose a `notHiddenSortedColors` in the controller, that the view doesn't have to filter anymore, there is no duplication. And your view will be more efficient, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the filtered options into an object watched by the model:

```
// HTML
<select 
    id="color" 
    ng-model="vm.color" 
    ng-options="opt.name for opt in vm.filteredColors = (
        vm.colors | filter: {hide: false} | orderBy: 'name'
    )">
</select>

// JS
vm.color = vm.filteredColors[0];
```

Like this, the model will be qual to the first `filtered` option.

If the option is not automatically chosen in the select, do it manually by dealing with the DOM through jQlite or pure javascript (at least, the model will be correct).

Answer (score -1):

in your controller do that:

```
this.myColor = this.colors[0];
```

and in the view

```
<select id="color" ng-model="vm.myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in vm.colors | filter: {hide: false} | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
```